# SQLite - create local db table structure using remote db

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database already defined in remote database (MySQL), for testing purpose, it contains only one table

```
Table Food (
  fid char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  fName varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Part of my function is to write an Android application that will be checking if the local db existed or not, if not , it will create the table based on the remote's db table structure. The problem is, how can I create a table same as the one in my remote database without hardcoding the sql statement.

I know JSON can be used to fetch data from remote DB to Android, but it seems it cannot support this function easily?
How can I do this?

Comment: Create `PHP` script that will return `JSON` containing 1 if db exists and 0 if not. create `GET` request and check result.

Comment: Geralt - I think the test for existence is on the LOCAL android db so no PHP/JSON required there - that is trivial.  the fetch is presumably for the complete table structures on the REMOTE db.

Comment: There is a test already written in my android application, the main question I am asking is: How can I replicate (or create) the table same as the one in my remote database server.

Comment: Did you read [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way this is done would be through a web service in the middle. 
[image]
 However, there is at least one blog post out there where someone connected directly to a MySQL db:[here](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/) where they basically add the MySQL JDBC Connector (3.0.17) to their project

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MysqlSample01Activity extends Activity {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://<server>:<port>/<database>";
    private static final String user = "<username>";
    private static final String pass = "<password>";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        testDB();
    }

    public void testDB() {
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            /* System.out.println("Database connection success"); */

            String result = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table_name");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next()) {
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            }
            tv.setText(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText(e.toString());
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: `JDBC` not working in Android. Except that is very big it's not recommended generally to use this kind of huge library that is used primary for Java `SE` a `EE`.